# Vi equivalent to "meta =" in Emacs?

Tags: vi

I would like to count characters in a selected block of text, in emacs I can use 'Meta =', which displays the following:

`Region has 7 lines, 417 characters.`

How can I do the same in Vi(m) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In visual mode, <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+g</kbd> will display word, character, line, and byte counts for the visually selected region.

See `:help v_g_Ctrl-g`.